Azure Pipeline AzureContainerApps@1 not deploying new image
I'm trying to deploy an Azure Container App using an Azure DevOps Pipeline. It's pushing a new image to my ACR but the Container App is not running the new image. My understanding is that it should be creating a new revision with the new image but the only revisions / replicas are a couple of weeks ago, possibly from when I tried to use the publish feature in Visual Studio to do it.
I'm new to container apps so I'm not sure if there's something that needs to be configured in Azure so that it automatically pulls the new image or if the pipeline is meant to do this.
My yaml is:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

name: '$(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:rr)' # Set build number

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'BackEnd/BackEnd.csproj'
- task: AzureContainerApps@1
  inputs:
    appSourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    azureSubscription: 'my-service-connection'
    acrName: 'MyAcr'
    containerAppName: 'my-backend-app'
    resourceGroup: 'myresourcegroup'
    imageToBuild: MyAcr.azurecr.io/my-backend-app:$(Build.BuildNumber)

Note: I've tweaked some azure resource names that I'd rather not be public
My container app has a managed identity and has the AcrPull permission for my ACR.
Edit: For clarity, I can see the new image in my ACR each time the pipeline is run, the problem is that the Container App is not using the new image, it's continuing to run the old image.
Can anyone help?
Update: With the suggestions from @Alvin below, I managed to get it deploying successfully but after 3 updates, it broke without any changes to the pipeline and is now stuck again.
I created a new container app as my original one appeared to be stuck and I couldn't create any revisions manually, either with CLI or from the portal UI.
I added a dotnet publish step to create an image directly and push to ACR, which is a LOT faster than using AzureContainerApps@1 for building.
I then updated the AzureContainerApps@1 to just deploy the image I'd pushed in the previous command.
On the 4th run of my pipeline, it took over 11 minutes instead of the previous 1m30 but looked as though it was successful. After this my container app in the portal showed as having 2 "Active Revisions" but with both "Scaled to 0". The app doesn't respond to incoming traffic and every time I've run the pipeline since, no further revisions are created; it only shows 2 active and 1 inactive (the first 3 that I created).

Hi @Mog0, See the updated the answer that works from my side.

After help from @Alvin Zhao - MSFT here, I discovered that you need to call AzureContainerApps@1 a second time with deploy parameters to actually deploy;
However my original container app seemed to be stuck and was showing a failed revision in addition to the running one and i couldn't create a new revision using the pipeline, CLI or the portal UI, so I needed to create a new container app.
After 3 successful deployments to the new app, it got stuck again showing 2 revisions, both with 0 replicas (meaning it didn't respond to any web requests). This eventually resolved itself after about an hour of downtime.
The same thing happened again after a few more deployments.
I now have the pipeline working reliably but I've abandoned the AzureContainerApps@1 command and instead I'm building and pushing the image with dotnet publish and then using the Azure CLI command that AzureContainerApps@1 was actually calling internally.
This seems to be both reliable but also takes less than a third of the time to actually run. My new pipeline yaml is
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

name: '$(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:rr)' # Set build number

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'MyACR-Connection'
    command: 'login'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build backend project, build image and push to ACR'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'BackEnd/BackEnd.csproj'
    arguments: '/t:PublishContainer -p:ContainerImageTag=$(Build.BuildNumber) -p:ContainerRegistry=myacr.azurecr.io'
    zipAfterPublish: false
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Update Azure Container App with new container'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my-azure-service-connection'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az containerapp update -n my-backend -g MyResGroup --image myacr.azurecr.io/my-backend:$(Build.BuildNumber)'

I then added to my csproj
<PropertyGroup>
    <IsPublishable>true</IsPublishable>
    <EnableSdkContainerSupport>true</EnableSdkContainerSupport>
    <ContainerRepository>my-backend</ContainerRepository>
    <ContainerFamily>jammy-chiseled</ContainerFamily>
    <ContainerRuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</ContainerRuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>


As far as I have tested based on the statement in this document, you pipeline task AzureContainerApps@1 with the property of imageToBuild will only build the customized ACR image rather than deploy it to your container app. You can still use it or Docker@2 to build your custom docker image, but also need to add another AzureContainerApps@1 step with the property of imageToDeploy.
Here is the sample pipeline for your reference.
variables:
  # ACR info
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'ACRSvcCnnWIF'
  imageRepository: 'containerapp/dotnet/sample'
  containerRegistry: 'azacrxxxxxx.azurecr.io'
  myAcr: azacrxxxxxx
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Azure container app info
  ARMSvcCnn: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFSub0'
  appName: 'azcontainerapp'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0
    # - task: Docker@2
    #   displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
    #   inputs:
    #     containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)'
    #     repository: '$(imageRepository)'
    #     command: 'buildAndPush'
    #     Dockerfile: '$(dockerfilePath)'
    #     tags: '$(tag)'
    - task: AzureContainerApps@1
      displayName: Build app image and push to ACR
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
        appSourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src'
        acrName: '$(myAcr)'
        containerAppName: '$(appName)'
        resourceGroup: 'rg-azcontainerapp'
        imageToBuild: $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
    - task: AzureContainerApps@1
      displayName: Deploy image to container app
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
        acrName: '$(myAcr)'
        containerAppName: '$(appName)'
        resourceGroup: 'rg-azcontainerapp'
        imageToDeploy: $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)

You may still double check if the new image is pushed in your ACR and if the container app is referencing that new image.


Your example appears to be using Web App, instead of Container App.
Note my example is using AzureContainerApps@1 but you are using AzureWebAppContainer@1.
Container app doesn't have an image on the Overview page.
Also, AzureContainerApps@1 builds the image directly if you don't provide a docker file. I can see the new image in my ACR each time I run the pipeline, but the problem is that the container app isn't using the new image.

What if you run az login as the ARM service connection underlying service principal and then run az containerapp update -n my-backend-app -g myresourcegroup -i MyAcr.azurecr.io/my-backend-app:xxx in CloudShell? Will the issue be reproduced?

Besides, you are only using imageToBuild property but not imageToDeploy as suggested here. Have you tried to build the image and then use the sample task in the document?

It wasn't clear from the docs that imageToDeploy was needed - I had interpreted as it still deploying without it, if you were using it to build.
I've changed my pipeline to build an image using dotnet publish and then calling the AzureContainerApps@1 to deploy. This has reduced the time taken down from 2m40 to 1m30 (even though it's actually doing the deploy step now)!! The builder seems to be slow.
I also had to create a new container app as something seemed to have broken in my existing one (I couldn't manually do an update with CLI or UI) and it also doesn't like docker.io as registry

Note: I'd tried switching from Azure CR to Docker.io (as it's free) at the same time as changing the deployment but it broke the process It didn't deploy until I switched back to Azure CR.

Seems I spoke too soon - it's broken again ☹️
I've added an update to my question above.

My app is very simple and the deployment from my side is very fast. So, you couldn't create a new container app with Azure CLI or web UI at the moment, right? Have you tried to create a new app with an older version of your app image to see if the issue was related to the image itself? I am not so familiar with container app than Azure DevOps. It seemed a different issue than what we discussed in this post. Would you post a new thread and engage more insights for the experts of container apps?

Thanks for your help @Alvin. I managed to get my pipeline working but gave up on using the AzureContainerApps@1 command. Doing it manually was significantly faster (more than 3x faster). I was having reliability issues but not sure if that was coincidence or actually caused by the command. I've added my own answer with details of what I did.

I had the same problem, I figured it out by deleting container app provisioned (from azure portal) and creating it again by hand (didn't have to delete conainer app env though)
After that the task did work properly.
This took me a lot of time to find, actually I tried to deploy a new revision on the container app resource that this task provisionned at first run, and discovered it was not possible (something like initial revision was missing and led to impossible to deploy a new one).
This put me in the idea that it was a provision issue.
Also, in parralel I tried to deploy with the az cli a new revision on this container app, and the return was Could not find a container app
I wonder if it's a bug or a special configuration on my side (despite my project is very very simple). if it is the case then opening a case on ms's side would be necessary, I wouldn't be surprised so because imo MS tends to abandon their azure devops in favor of github one (repo and pipelines)...
